# VSCode adding a prefix of 'untitled' to URI when using json(loadTextContent())

Tags: vscode-extensions

I'm pretty new to using the BICEP extension in VSCode and while going through some exercise files from a class I am receiving an error when attempting to reference a JSON file with some simple parameters defined. The error in the editor shows that it can't find the file at the URI, but it is adding "Untitled":/c:/ to the path.

I've tried switching my default terminal - changed the file to a different relative path at the root, but it continues to have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Crap - I just needed to save the file I was working with - dangit - it's been a long week - thank god it's Friday

Comment: In that case I suggest you just delete your question.